# Connect Openfire using XMPP

Tags: ios, xmpp, openfire

I am new to `IOS`. I am making chat app using `XMPP` and `Openfire` server. But i don't know how to connect with `Openfire` using `XMPP`. So how can I connect with `Openfire` server using `XMPP`?

Comment: Hey there @dhvl golakiya.  Can you please help me connecting XMPP to openfire. I am searching for the answer for two weeks and didn't get any response. So if you are got any answer to your question .Please let me know how you made this happen. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26750301/connect-openfire-server-to-xmpp-framework-ios.  You can post your answer to this question. Any help would be appreciated. Please post answer with some snippet of code.Thanks.